# How to change Textbox text dynamically (when user is typing) to XXXXX using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, masking

Here textbox field is masked. When the user enters text, I want it to change to (XXX)-XX-XXXX dynamically (Without leaving focus of textbox).

```
     $("#textbox").mask("(999)-99-9999");
```

Comment: Does the jquery code not do the task? Is there another issue there?

Comment: If you change the entered input to "X's" with jQuery you will lose the entered values unless you store them elsewhere. When you go to get them back they will be "X's". Why not just set the field as a password field and let the browser hide them for you?

Comment: @gforce301  I can use PasswordFor but I cannot have input mask on that field. If I use input mask on PasswordFor, even before I enter any text the field is filled with dots, Is there a way I can use PassowrdFor and input mask at the same time?